# test onclick <a> tag which renders another component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component looks like this.

```
return (
<div>
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol className="breadcrumb"}
        >
           
                    <li className="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
       

            <li className="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">activepage</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
</div>
```

);

and i am test cases for this which looks like below:

```
describe("BreadCrumb Component", () => {
let shallowWrapper: ShallowWrapper;
let breadCrumbWrapper: ReactWrapper;

it('should be a div Component', () => {
shallowWrapper = shallow(<BreadCrumb ></BreadCrumb>);
expect(shallowWrapper.type()).toBe('div')
breadCrumbWrapper = mount(<BreadCrumb ></BreadCrumb>);
const breadcrumbvalues = breadCrumbWrapper.find('nav').find('ol').find('li').map(col => col.text());
expect(breadcrumbvalues).toHaveLength(2);
expect(breadcrumbvalues[0]).toEqual("Home");
expect(breadcrumbvalues[1]).toEqual("activepage");
breadCrumbWrapper.find('nav').find('ol').find('li').at(0).simulate('click');
......Here after clicking i want to test the component render which is (/home)...
```

})

can anyone help me how should i test onclick tag whether it rendered another component or not. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can test the anchor tag in two ways.
First, check `href` value in the anchor tag like this

```
expect(breadCrumbWrapper.find('nav').find('ol').find('li').at(0).find("a").prop("href")).toEqual("/home");
```

Secondly, you can check the `location.pathname` value after simulating `click` event

```
expect(breadCrumbWrapper.props().location.pathname).toEqual("/home");
```

Or

```
expect(window.location.pathname).toEqual("/home");
```

Comment: while using expect(window.location.pathname).toEqual("/home"); i am getting this error   Expected: "/home"
    Received: "/"

Comment: and also how can i check whether home component rendered or not?

Comment: @PavanSai What about `expect(breadCrumbWrapper.props().location.pathname).toEqual("/home");` this ?

Comment: that is giving error .it was not able to recognize location